# How to estimate the integral of Riemann zeta function with error term trends to zero as T trends to infinity?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

$\zeta(s)$ denotes the Riemann zeta function. For $T>0$ large enough $$\int_{T}^{2T}|\zeta(\frac{1}{3} + it) 
\ \zeta(\frac{2}{3} + it)|dt = \ ? $$

Comment: See Ingham’s “Mean-Value Theorems in the Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function” (Theorem A does the trick). In fact I believe your case reduces to work of Littlewood/Hardy-Littlewood on second moments by just using the functional equation + Stirling, but anyway.

Comment: What have you tried?